# Planning to move to SSD from HDD in Laptop, need assistance

Tags: partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

I'm currently using a Dell Vostro 3650 laptop and I'm planning to move to SSD by swapping out the stock HDD that came with it. Decided to go with this SSD here : http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct500bx100ssd1

So, I have a couple of questions regarding that. Right now the way it's laid out is I have dual operating systems : Windows 7 and Ubuntu on the hard disk. If I were to use the SSD, I would need to swap out the primary HDD with it and install the HDD in the place of the DVD-Drive. I believe I can't have the SSD added in the DVD- Drive bay.

Considering that, is it fine if I were to partition the SSD for my operating systems similar to what I did to my HDD? Are there any long term effects or anything that I should be aware of if I am partitioning my SSD?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is fine to partition the SSD similar to the way you have partitioned your existing hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and simplest way to do this is to purchase a USB 2.5 inch HDD caddy to help do the copy, and use acronis or macrium reflect to do a block to block copy (this ensures that both operating systems on both partitions are copied fully).

To move one of the operating systems to another disk is also possible, but problems may occur with booting unless you are good with grub2.

There are no long term effects I can think of apart from a much faster laptop.

The SSD can be placed in the cd sata bay, but most laptops use a slower sata data rate for the cdrom, so your SSD will also be using the slower rate.

Comment: Hi Johnny, thank you for your response. Much appreciated. I am however planning to re-install fresh copies of Operating Systems after installing the new SSD. So it would be as if a new laptop is being configured. I was just checking whether partitioning a SSD like we do for HDD would have any complications as a lot of articles online say a lot of things about partitioning a SSD.

Comment: I never partition disks as I find that I lose space as both partitions need space to function - If you have the caddy to replace the cdrom, put another hdd/ssd in there - It may run slightly slower, but nothing that noticeable.